# RateCARD API MeterID doesn't match with UsageAggregation API MeterID

Tags: api, azure, azure-billing-api

I have difficulties to match meterID (GUID) from rateCARD API response and meterID from UsageAggregation API response. I even looked at this Table
( *azure.microsoft.com/de-de/support/guid-migration/*) 
but this doesn't help either. The meterID from UsageAggregatio API response matches with old GUID, but neither the old GUID nor the new one doesn’t match with the id in rateCARD API response.
This is my request queries.

*management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubID} /providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&reportedstartTime=2016-05-22+00%3a00%3a00Z&reportedEndTime=2016-05-23+00%3a00%3a00Z&aggregationGranularity=Daily&showDetails=true*

*management.azure.com/subscriptions/{SubID} /providers/Microsoft.Commerce/RateCard?api-version=2015-06-01-preview&$filter=OfferDurableId%20eq%20'MS-AZR-0025P'%20and%20Currency%20eq%20'EUR'%20and%20Locale%20eq%20'de-DE'%20and%20RegionInfo%20eq%20'DE'*

Can anyone help me on this please?

***UPDATE***

**Here is an example of such response. I get usage aggregations with meter id from UsageAggregation API.**

```
"id": "/subscriptions/ /providers/Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregates/Daily_BRSDT_20160520_0000",
      "name": "Daily_BRSDT_20160520_0000",
      "type": "Microsoft.Commerce/UsageAggregate",
      "properties": {
        "subscriptionId": "5948833b-863b-4fde-9059-e0c93523da27",
        "usageStartTime": "2016-05-23T00:00:00+00:00",
        "usageEndTime": "2016-05-24T00:00:00+00:00",
        "meterName": "Compute Hours",
        "meterRegion": "EU North",
        "meterCategory": "Virtual Machines",
        "meterSubCategory": "BASIC.A2 VM (Windows)",
        "unit": "Hours",
        "instanceData": "{\"Microsoft.Resources\":{\"resourceUri\":\"/subscriptions/
        "meterId": "782591e9-abf5-4c5b-b764-aaf746e71e85",
        "infoFields": {},
        "quantity": 1.600012
      }
```

**I didn’t get exact entry for this resource from RateCard API, this is the nearest resource I could find. The entry for resource listed in UsageAggregation API response doesn’t exist in RateCard API response.**

```
"MeterId": "5261a49e-27cc-4b42-b264-15e332882525",
      "MeterName": "Computestunden",
      "MeterCategory": "Virtual Machines",
      "MeterSubCategory": "VM BASIC.A2 (Windows)",
      "Unit": "Stunden",
      "MeterTags": [],
      "MeterRegion": "Brasilien, Süden",
      "MeterRates": {
        "0": 0.1501074
```

***UPDATE 25.05.2016***
[Offer ID screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hGkH6.png)

Comment: Can you update your question with mismatched ids? I have seen this happen a number of times where meter id returned by usage API is nowhere to be found in the data returned by rate card API.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response.

Comment: So I ran the same query against my Azure Subscription and I was able to see that meter id. Here's the response I got (at least part of it): http://pastebin.com/1n8J0Xqz

Comment: The result looks good, exactly like I was hoping to get. Do you have any idea why I don’t get complete rate card?

Comment: Honestly, I have no idea :). Will it be possible for you to copy the entire  response somewhere (may be on pastebin.com) and I can take a look?

Comment: Please. 
http://pastebin.com/uyxGWQ4V

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Interesting! I don't see that meter either. Can you check the Offer ID for your Subscription? Is it `MS-AZR-0025P`?

Comment: Yes it is MS-AZR-0025P, check the screenshot in the post update.

Comment: I am inclined to think that it's a bug with the Usage API. As I mentioned in my 1st comment, I have seen this kind of thing with my subscription as well where no information found in rate card about meters reported in the usage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried running exact same project on azure VM and it works just fine. Apparently this issue is caused by infrastructure.